# Connecting to Exchange PowerShell from a Linux machine

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, python

We currently have a Python script that automates user creation tasks on our servers. This script provisions users in OpenLDAP and ActiveDirectory by using [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/).

Now, I want to modify some Exchange attributes as well in this script. I want to know if there is a way to interact with the Exchange Powershell remotely from a UNIX machine. Specifically using Python but if anyone knows any other method, I might be able to use it along with the [pexpect library](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).

Comment: version of Exchange, version of AD DC's?

Comment: Sorry about omitting that: Exchange 2010 and 2008 R2 DC's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell can be made available via SSH in at least two ways:

- via Cygwin ([tutorial](http://www.datacrash.net/howtos/howto/using-powershell-through-ssh.html))
- via commercial software called [PowerShell Inside](http://www.powershellinside.com/)

PowerShell scripts also can be invoked via xml-rpc ([TechNet forum link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/98f6b08b-eba5-4f48-9d68-5e19dff85fba/)).

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be accessing Exchange 2010 through web services, using [the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13082) to see some examples, as well as [PowerShell examples here](http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2011/04/powershell-script-cmdlets-for-managing-e-mail-items-using-the-exchange-web-services-managed-api/).  Would love to see some of your end results posted here to help others.